# Создание процесса Python с автозапуском

Tags: python, windows

1. Есть Python скрипт, сделать чтобы он висел в процессах
2. Добавить его в стартап

Мне нужно в самом python скрипте. Т.е чтобы при запуске скрипта он сам добавился в автозагрузку, и висел в процессах.

windows От 7 и старше.

Прошу помощи.

Comment: А в чем проблема прописать в стартап C:\PythonXX\python.exe script.py? Ну а чтобы он висел - это уже в самом скрипте надо делать...

Comment: Какая ОС? Питон много где работает

Comment: Система --> Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Чтобы скрипт висел в процессах необходимо, чтобы он не завершался после запуска. Например, содержал бесконечный цикл

   ```
   import time
   while True:
       # your code here

       # задержка, чтобы не перегружать процессор
       time.sleep(5)
   ```
2. Одним из вариантом добавления Python-скрипта в автозапуск является размещение служебного .cmd-скрипта в папке Автозагрузки (`Пуск` --> `Все программы` --> `Автозагрузка`). Расположенный там исполняемый файл будет запускаться при старте системы.
   Пример скрипта

   ```
   rem изменение рабочего каталога скрипта с папки автозагрузки на папку Python-скрипта
   pushd path\to\script\folder

   rem вызов Python-скрипта
   start python script_name.py
   ```

rem возвращение рабочего каталога обратно
popd

У скрипта можно создать ярлык и вынести его в удобное место.

Comment: Мне нужно в самом python скрипте. Т.е чтобы при запуске скрипта он сам добавился в автозагрузку, и висел в процессах.

Comment: @Alban а как запускается python-скрипт в первый раз? Какие версии Windows, от 7 и старше?

Comment: windows От 7 и старше.