# Как добавить python скрипт в автозапуск в самом коде

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно чтоб при первом запуске скрипта он добавлял сам себя в автозапуск. На windows 7 и выше.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание процесса Python с автозапуском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625884/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-python-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 1):

```
from winreg import *
from os import path
   
PathFile = path.abspath(__file__)
# (Если будете компилировать файл в ехе тогда PathFile = path.abspath(__file__)[:-2]+'exe')

def Startup():
    StartupKey = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                    r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
                    0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    SetValueEx(StartupKey, 'name', 0, REG_SZ, PathFile)
    CloseKey(StartupKey)

Startup()
```